Tikz node position along edge, expressed in absolute distance
Is it possible to set node position in absolute distance along an edge, rather than using pos=<x> where pos=0 is at edge start and pos=1 at edge end (which are relative positions between the two edges extremities)?
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=1pt, draw, circle}]
\draw (0,0) -- node[pos=2mm] {} (1,-.2);  % doesn't work
\draw (0,0) -- node[pos=.5]  {} (1, .2);  % not what i'm looking for
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Just to confirm: a. the node shall appear along the linear path (it might be curved in general), b. at an absolute distance, i.e. the intersect of, in your example, a circle with radius 2mm and said (non-)linear path? What shall happen, if the path is shorter than your absolute pos? // What prevents you from placing said node independently from the path? // Thank your

My edges are not that easy of course, but thanks for the greant answers that were given !

This can be done with the decorations.markings library, which accepts absolute distances or relative positions. This has the advantage of working on curved edges as well as straight ones.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}

\tikzset{marknode/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with{\node[inner sep=1pt, draw, circle]{};}},
    postaction=decorate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[marknode=2mm] (0,0) -- (1,-.2);
\draw[marknode=.5] (0,0) -- (1, .2);
\draw[marknode=3mm] (0,0) to[bend right] (1, -.4);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


With the calc libray. Section 13.5 Coordinate Calculations in pgfmanual'documentation.
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=1pt, draw, circle}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,-.2);    
\draw (A) --  (B);  % doesn't work
\node at ($(A)!2mm!(B)$){};
\draw (0,0) -- node[pos=.5]  {} (1, .2);  % not what i'm looking for
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


